# Функция вызывается дважды, текст отображается некорректно и чтоб кнопка заработала нужно её вызывать дважды в телеграм боте

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telebot

Недавно я начал изучать создание ботов для Python. Я решил создать бота, отображающего данные, которые он принимает через API, и столкнулся со следующими проблемами:
Все ошибки в коде я пометил комментарием и хешем:

1. #1 вызывается дважды прежде чем вызывается #2.
2. #3 В момент, когда сообщение message.text должно было вывести в Daily, он отображает Russia.
3. #4 кнопка возврата должна быть вызвана один раз, а затем должна быть вызвана любая другая кнопка, чтобы сработала кнопка возврата.

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def chose_country(message):
    country = None
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)  # Create buttonboard
    markup.add(ru, uk, by)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Choose a country:'.format(message.from_user), #ПОЧЕМУ ТО ВЫЗЫВАЕТСЯ ДВАЖДЫ
                     reply_markup=markup) #1
    if 'Russia' in message.text:
        country = 'ru'

    elif 'Ukraine' in message.text:
        country = 'ua'

    elif 'Belarus' in message.text:
        country = 'by'

    if country is not None:
        if country in country_list:
            bot.register_next_step_handler(message, chose_mode, country) #2


def chose_mode(message, country):
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    markup.add(latest_info, all_info)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,
                     'Choose to receive recent or general country information:'.format(message.from_user),
                     reply_markup=markup)
    print(message.text) #ПОЧЕМУ ОН ВЫВОДИТ Russia  а не Daily    #3
    if 'Daily' in message.text:
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)  # Create buttonboard
        markup.add(cnfrmd, rcvrd, crit, dths, bck)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id,
                         'Select the information you would like to know:'.format(message.from_user),
                         reply_markup=markup)
        mode = 'daily'
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, chose_info, country, mode)
    elif 'Total' in message.text:
        print("daaaaa")
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)  # Create buttonboard
        markup.add(cnfrmd, rcvrd, crit, dths, bck)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id,
                         'Select the information you would like to know:'.format(message.from_user),
                         reply_markup=markup)
        mode = 'total'
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, chose_info, country, mode)

    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id,
                         'Please try again:'.format(message.from_user))
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, chose_country)


def chose_info(message, country, mode):
    try:
        text = ApiConnector.get_data(country)  # get json info about country
    except:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id,
                         'An error occurred while getting data, please try again later... '.format(message.from_user))
        print("Cannot connection to API")
    if 'message' not in text:
        if 'Back' in message.text:
            bot.register_next_step_handler(message, chose_country) #4
```

[image: дважды вызывать назад чтоб он вызвался]

[image: двойной вызов первой функции]

Answer (score 1):

Ну по вашему коду вы так и запрограммировали.

1. Первый раз вошли в `chose_country()` - напечатали "'Choose a country:'", переменная `country` остаётся всё ещё `None` (вы же ещё из функции даже не возвращались, и заранее в `message.text` вряд ли была страна), соответственно обработчик №2 в конце не устанавливается, а остаётся прежним. При втором заходе на входе уже страна, но сообщение (и клавиатура) у вас пишется в любом случае, хотя наконец в конце меняется обработчик на №2.
2. Сработал обработчик `chose_mode()`, но клавиатура у вас была выведена обработчиком №1 (см. конец предыдущего пункта), где вы и выбрали Russia.
3. И здесь абсолютно то же самое. Обработчик пишет сообщение, выводит кнопки и почему-то тут же их проверяет. Естественно `message.text` просто не может им соответствовать, т.к. обработчик был вызван из предыдущей клавиатуры, а новую вы только в нём выводите.

Вот и происходит у вас везде - на первый заход выводятся сообщение и клавиатура, но вход её, естественно, не соответствует. На второй заход наконец вход соответствует тому, чего ожидает обработчик, но тоже самое сообщение и клавиатура в любом случае печатается снова, хотя обработчик переключается на следующий (который ожидает ввод совсем других слов).

Т.е. в общем случае вам, прежде чем переключаться на другой обработчик, необходимо вывести нужную клавиатуру, которая будет соответствовать новому обработчику.

```
def print_keyboard(message, text, *buttons):
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)  # Create buttonboard
    markup.add(*buttons)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text, reply_markup=markup)

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def chose_country(message):
    country = None
    if 'Russia' in message.text:
        country = 'ru'
    elif 'Ukraine' in message.text:
        country = 'ua'
    elif 'Belarus' in message.text:
        country = 'by'

    if country not in country_list:
        print_keyboard(message, 'Choose a country:', 
                       ru, uk, by)
    else:
        print_keyboard(message, 'Choose to receive recent or general country information:',
                       latest_info, all_info)
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, chose_mode, country) #2


def chose_mode(message, country):
    if 'Daily' in message.text:
        print_keyboard(message, 'Select the information you would like to know:', 
                       cnfrmd, rcvrd, crit, dths, bck)
        mode = 'daily'
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, chose_info, country, mode)
    elif 'Total' in message.text:
        print_keyboard(message, 'Select the information you would like to know:',
                       cnfrmd, rcvrd, crit, dths, bck)
        mode = 'total'
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, chose_info, country, mode)

    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id,
                         'Please try again:'.format(message.from_user))
        print_keyboard(message, 'Choose a country:',
                       ru, uk, by)
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, chose_country)


def chose_info(message, country, mode):
    try:
        text = ApiConnector.get_data(country)  # get json info about country
    except:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id,
                         'An error occurred while getting data, please try again later... '.format(message.from_user))
        print("Cannot connection to API")
    if 'message' not in text:
        if 'Back' in message.text:
            print_keyboard(message, 'Choose a country:',
                           ru, uk, by)
            bot.register_next_step_handler(message, chose_country) #4
```

Comment: Большое вам спасибо, очень помогли :)